# file_put_contents failed to open stream: no such file or directory (only locally)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have a PHP script that I've added to a cron job, although the PHP script is not able to be ran locally.

If I access it through the web browser, it works 100%. If I access it through terminal, it reproduces the behavior below.

**Test:**

```
$ php5 /path/test.php
```

**Error:**

```
file_put_contents(folder/filename.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/test.php on line 11
```

**Code:**

```
$host = 'https://www.google.com/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$host);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('folder/filename.txt', $status);
```

I don't believe permissions are an issue since the error doesn't state anything, but the `folder` is set to 777 and the php script is set to +w through chmod

Any help would be appreciated, this is all new to me.

**Folder Structure:**

```
/path/test.php
/path/folder/filename.txt
```

Comment: the script will be running with its "home" directory being YOUR account's home dir. if your `folder` is actually `/path/folder`, the script will actually be trying to use `/home/andrew_wilson/folder/filename.txt`.

Comment: Added my folder structure to the OP, I've tried using full path and see the same error. The odd thing is this works when accessed directly through www

Comment: Actually after retrying that again, the error message changes to permission denied. After setting permissions through chmod it all works now. You can post that as an answer, I'm still unclear on why it would create the file that didn't exist when sent through WWW but would not do it locally, even though the folder itsself is set to 777 permissions

Comment: yeah. strange. but don't forget you need permissions on all the folders leading up to where you're putting the file, and on the file itself if it already exists. changing perms on dir `d` in a `/a/b/c/d` is pointless if your user ID doesn't have the rights to be in `a` or `b` or `c` to begin with. e.g. a wide open safety deposit box in a locked bank vault.

Comment: @MarcB if you post this as an answer, I'll give you credit so other's have a clear path of resolution